# Cannot add an append an array into a dictionary that has an empty array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary, singleton

I have a Profile Data singleton class as follows.

I am trying to store data into an empty array in a dictionary .

After appending data to the array also the count of the array is 0.

```
        class ProfileData{

            static let sharedInstance = ProfileData()

             var artistProfileDict = [String : Profile]()
             var loggedInUserProfile = Profile(artistName: "John Smith", artistDescription: "Admiral of New England, English soldier, explorer, and author.", totalLikes: "174", totalViews: "200", totalFollowing: "100",totalFollowers:"50",imageUrl:"image_singer", feeds:[] )


            private init() {
                getProfilesDictionary()
            }

             func getProfilesDictionary()->[String: Profile]{
                artistProfileDict["John Smith"] = loggedInUserProfile
                return artistProfileDict
            }

            func add(array: Feed, artistName: String) {

               artistProfileDict[artistName]!.feeds.append(array)

            }

        }
```

In another view Controller I am trying to add an array to the empty array in the dictionary as follows

```
    let newFeed = Feed(profilePicture: "image",artistName: "New", 
    videoUrl: "url",videoTitle:"New", videoViews: "160",likes: 
    "200",shoutouts: "200",comments: [],votes: "50", dateCreated: Date(),
     userActivity :"This user liked your video")


ProfileData.sharedInstance.add(array: newFeed,artistName:"John Smith")
```

After appending the array to the empty array in the dictionary I still get the count of the array as 0.

I am not able to figure out the problem here. Any help will appreciated . Thank you.

Profile class

```
struct Profile {
    var artistName: String
    var artistDescription: String
    var totalLikes: String
    var totalViews: String
    var totalFollowing: String
    var totalFollowers: String
    var imageUrl: String
    var feeds : [Feed]

    init(artistName: String,artistDescription:String,totalLikes:String,totalViews:String,totalFollowing:String,totalFollowers:String,imageUrl:String, feeds:[Feed]) {

        self.artistName = artistName
        self.artistDescription = artistDescription
        self.totalLikes = totalLikes
        self.totalViews = totalViews
        self.totalFollowing = totalFollowing
        self.totalFollowers = totalFollowers
        self.imageUrl = imageUrl
        self.feeds = feeds
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show the Profile class code?

Comment: I have updated the question @Sahil

Comment: No need to create a initializer when using structs if it is not custom

Comment: `struct Profile {
    var artistName: String
    var artistDescription: String
    var totalLikes: String
    var totalViews: String
    var totalFollowing: String
    var totalFollowers: String
    var imageUrl: String
    var feeds : [Feed]
}` has the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working fine

```
ProfileData.sharedInstance.add(array: newFeed,artistName:"John Smith")

ProfileData.sharedInstance.artistProfileDict["John Smith"]?.feeds.count // 1
```

Probably you are using wrong class `ArtistProfileData` instead of `ProfileData`.

Comment: No I am using the same class. I have made a mistake while posting the question.

Comment: i have checked it and feeds count returning 1 after adding the feed element.

Comment: Thanks its works all fine. I had to do a clean and rebuild. Xcode behaves unexpectedly!

Comment: Glad to hear :)